# SVG animation delay not working - repeated instantly

Tags: svg

I am trying to create an SVG animation (basically I am moving a filter). How can I delay the animation after it is completed, so it does not restart immediatly. I tried setting an id and then adding the id.end + time but this is not working - the animation is repeated immediatly. Thanks for the help!

```
<mask id="mask1_1_7" style="mask-type:alpha" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="0" y="0" width="92" height="82">
<rect id="MovingLayer_2" width="92" height="82" fill="#C4C4C4">


<animateTransform id="op" 
                      attributeName="transform"
                      attributeType="XML"
                      type="translate"
                      from="0 0"
                      to="92 0"
                      dur="3s"
                      begin="0s;op.end+3s" 
                      repeatCount="indefinite"
                      />


</rect>
</mask>
```

Comment: Use `repeatCount="1"`

Comment: If this was the right answer don't hesitate to reply to the question @enxaneta so that the question can be marked as resolved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @enxaneta pointed out, using `repeatCount="1"` fixed the issue